# How to cast a pointer (make it bigger)

Tags: c

My program/process exited abnormally? I doubt something is wrong with the following code:

There are two typedef TYPE1, TYPE2. (TYPE1's size is bigger than TYPE2)

```
TYPE1 var1;
TYPE2 var2;
....
....var2 has been assigned.
....
memset(&var1, 0, sizeof(var1));
memcpy(&var1, (TYPE1 *)&var2, sizeof(TYPE1)）;
printf("....");
```

1. Cast var2 may cause accessing the illegal memory which may lead to segmentation fault? I thought it may mess up the data following the var2 in memory, but cannot make segmentation fault? I found my program exit here, since the following printf() did not print anything.
2. Cast will ruin the data following var2 in memory even if it is only read (var2 is just source of memcpy().
3. what happens if I change it like memcpy(&var1, (TYPE1 *)&var2, sizeof(TYPE2)）;

Thanks.

Comment: The output from `printf` is typically buffered. Your code may have made it past the `printf` before the crash. You may want to use a debugger or at least post more code here.

Comment: You don't need the casts. Casts, in C, are almost always wrong and point to a need to refactor. Other than that, in the `memcpy()` call you are trying to access data through `&var2` after the end of the object (`sizeof var1 > sizeof var2`).

Comment: @pmg - may I qualify "Casts, in C, are almost always wrong"? "casting pointers to void pointers is almost always wrong because it is never necessary" (to be truthful, I can't think of any circumstance when assigning any pointer to a void * needs a cast in modern C. so maybe I'm being wishy-washy), I wouldn't like to think of people thinking "... (unsigned int)c" or "foo((double)i", is in the same class of wrongness.

Comment: @gbulmer: Off of the top of my head, the only places a cast is required is when passing arguments to variadic functions and when using functions declared in `<ctype.h>`. Most other casts can better be done by compiler's implicit conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first: you don't need to cast `&var2` to `TYPE1*` when using `memcpy`. `memcpy` expects `void*`, and any pointer type can be cast to `void*`.

The problem here is, when `TYPE1` is bigger than `TYPE2` and you are copying the data from `var2` to `var1` using `sizeof(TYPE1)` as the size, memcpy will eventually read from beyond the memory occupied by `var2`. As a consequence, you are accessing memory you are not allowed to access. Hence, a segmentation fault is the best you could have gotten there, since that error might also have be gone unnoticed for quite some time until it really could have caused trouble (undefined behavior is the key phrase here).

When you copy only `sizeof(TYPE2)` bytes from `var2` to `var1`, you are ok in terms of memory access (as long as `TYPE1` is really bigger than `TYPE2`).

Answer (score 1):

**I.** It *might* cause Segmentation fault but not because you have casted into `(TYPE1*)` but because you are reading `sizeof(TYPE1)` from `var2`.Also it'll not mess up data after `var2`. In fact, you don't need to worry about data corruptions. The very purpose of Segmentation fault is to prevent such illegal memory accesses, whether read or write

**II.** Will not ruin data following var2. The prototype of `memcpy` is

```
`void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );`
```

Observe the `const`. So its guaranteed that `source` data will not be modified. Also casts can in no way decide whether it'll be an invalid memory access or not. The number of bytes you are trying to copy, source and destination sizes are what matter.

**III.** As others noted, casts are immaterial, and in this case since you are copying from a smaller data structure to a larger one, no segmentation fault will arise.

Comment: what you mean will cause segmentation fault but not mess up data  is  seg-fault more preferable ? :) as a sidenote casting while passing to  memcpy would not help since the parameters are always void*

Comment: @keety The OP seems to be worried about data corruption, thats why I mentioned it that no such thing will happen. Anyways, I edited my answer to make my intent clearer

Comment: Does **I:** guarantee a segmentation fault? Or it is Undefined Behavior? Your answer seems to confidently indicate segmentation fault as the only possible outcome which is not true.

Answer (score 0):

I believe an important point is missed here.

You do not make pointers bigger or shorter. All pointers of whether int, char, float are of the same size and just contain an address (with the only exception in old times when we had near or far pointers in c in 16 bit DOS times). Still size of pointer is the same as size of integer on a machine.

So the question title is misleading. But you would ask why do we need types with pointers at all?

When we cast a pointer from say TYPE_1 * to TYPE_2 * we are basically telling what type of variable will that pointer be referring to and HOW MANY BYTES WILL IT SKIP when we write for instance

```
int * a;
a++; // skips four bytes if it is a 32 bit integer/machine

double *b;
b++; // skips 8 bytes
```